# Gstreamer H264 RTP

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp, receiver, gst-launch-1.0

I am using GStreamer 1.0 to capture and display a video broadcast by an MGW ACE encode(or from a VLC itself), I am using RTP with H264

I have read that the sender's SPS and PPS information is needed in order to decode.
Both information is added in the sprop-parameter-sets parameter.

But if I can't get that information, is there any way I can decode and display without adding that parameter?

My Payload is the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port = 9001 caps = "application / x-rtp, media = (string) video"! rtph264depay! decodebin! autovideosink
```

I have verified that from two different hosts, one to emit and another to receive through gstreamer, I have no problem, I can send and receive it without problem.
But when I try to receive a video from a MGW ACE encode from a VLC itself, I cannot display it.

Answer (score 0):

Some RTP streaming scenarios repeat SPS/PPS periodically in-band before each IDR-frame. However I believe they do for convenience for that particular case. If i remember correctly RTP defines SPS/PPS transmission to occur out of band, via SDP information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
Is there a solution to be able to solve it from the gstreamer client?
Using the VLC as a client, I get to see the video without having to add the SDP.